# Зависимость select и div

Tags: php, html, битрикс

Есть select

```
<select class="b-ss">
<?foreach ($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):
$class = "";
if ($ar["CHECKED"])
$class.= " selected";
if ($ar["DISABLED"])
$class.= " disabled";
?>
<li>
<option value="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" class="bx_filter_param_label<?=$class?>"><?=$ar["VALUE"]?></option>
</li>
<?endforeach?>
</select>
```

и div

```
<div class="bx_filter_select_popup" data-role="dropdownContent" style="display: none;">
<?foreach ($arItem["VALUES"] as $val => $ar):
if ($ar["CHECKED"])
$class.= " selected";
if ($ar["DISABLED"])
$class.= " disabled";
?>
<li>
<label for="<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" class="bx_filter_param_label<?=$class?>" data-role="label_<?=$ar["CONTROL_ID"]?>" onclick="smartFilter.selectDropDownItem(this, '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($ar["CONTROL_ID"])?>')"><?=$ar["VALUE"]?></label>
</li>
<?endforeach?>
</ul>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поскажите, как в зависимости от выбранного `option` активировать соответствующий `label`

Comment: Нужно активировать label в div`е

Answer (score 1):

Можно повесить событие `onChange` на `select`, делая по нему `trigger('click')` на нужном лейбле.